# Allow users to filter a list using text input on SharePoint Online

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, filter

I have a requirement to allow users to filter a list by entering a search string.

I've been following the guide here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-HA010250989.aspx#BMs1

I get as far as "Click the Web Part menu for the Text Filter Web Part, point to Connections, point to Send Filter Values To, and then click the name of the List View Web Part to which you want to link."

For me the connections menu won't expand so I can't link the webparts together.

Anyone else experienced this?  Is this just yet another feature that's broken in SharePoint Online or is my flu riddled brain missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm using SharePoint Online and for me the webpart is working.
You can see how to connect the filter on my screenshot.

I guess your problem is you're not using internet explorer or you are blocking popups (as the connection menu is blocked by default).

[image: Example to connect filter webpart]

Comment: I hadn't thought of browser.  I was using IE9 but it's working in firefox, go figure.

Comment: maybe you have enabled the enhanced security setting (Aka jscript breaker)?

Comment: Dunno, it's odd.  I've tried turning pretty all the security settings, pop up blocker etc off in IE and it still won't show that menu.  FF is working fine though so I'll just use that.  Strange it seems to only be that menu that's not working for me.